# VerifyError, or using overridePendingTransition while maintaining compatibility?

Tags: android, backwards-compatibility, verifyerror

I've got an application that uses overridePendingTransition to do some custom animations upon transitioning from one activity to the other. This was made available in Android 2.0, but I want to make the application work on Android 1.6. I figured if I just checked that android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.DONUT, and if not, don't do the overridePendingTransition.

However, I get a VerifyError, which I assume is caused by this:
    VFY: Unable to resolve virtual method 346: ../../Login: overridePendingTransition (II)V

Is it not possible to use newer functionality conditionally based on the SDK version?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Is it not possible to use newer functionality conditionally based on the SDK version?

Yes, it is.

I am going to guess that your code looks like this:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.DONUT) {
  overridePendingTransition(...);
}
```

If I am correct, then that will not work. The VM will attempt to find `overridePendingTransition()` when the class is loaded, not when that `if()` statement is executed.

Instead, you should be able to do this:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.DONUT) {
  SomeClassDedicatedToThisOperation.overridePendingTransition(this, ...);
}
```

where the implementation of `overridePendingTransition()` in `SomeClassDedicatedToThisOperation` just calls `overridePendingTransition()` on the supplied `Activity`.

So long as `SomeClassDedicatedToThisOperation` is not used anywhere else, its class will not be loaded until you are inside your `if()` test, and you will not get the `VerifyError`.